# Passing commands to cmd from powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry

I want to make changes to a registry key through this command:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll" /v TcpDynamicPorts /t REG_SZ /d 6363 /f
```

This has to happen in a cmd, which i ran as administrator through powershell with this command in a batch file:

```
powershell.exe Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb runAs
```

I need a UAC Prompt for the user to input his admin credentials to make it as user friendly as possible.
Now my question: How do i pass the reg add command to the console which i started as administrator?

Comment: Why not just run the whole thing in the powershell console  ? why do you need to use the cmd console ?

Comment: Why dont u just directly set the Regkey using Powershell? Why would you take the extra step with the cmd?

Comment: I want to setup a silent install for SQLServer 2014 with a configuration file. To finish the setup, i need to change the dynamic TCP/IP port. This is not possible without administrative rights. And since we have multiple servers with probably different admin accounts, i need the user to input the creds. We want to keep the user input to a minimum to avoid any errors caused by the user. I could just start the powershell as admin, but then i wouldn't know how to pass the regedit command to the powershell either.

Comment: You should take a look at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/02/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/ . Powershell also offers easy Credential-Parsing with a prompt using `Get-Credential`.

Comment: `I could just start the powershell as admin, but then i wouldn't know how to pass the regedit command to the powershell either` - Just use powershell to perform the task that `reg` is doing. Either use `reg` like you would from cmd or use powershell commands to do it

Comment: So now i can start the powershell with a UAC prompt like this:
    `start-process powershell.exe -verb runas`
But i want to tell that elevated powershell to run the reg add command without having to input anything. Simply using a ";" to chain commands doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your command in `-ArgumentList` parameter like this:

```
powershell.exe "Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList 'REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll" /v TcpDynamicPorts /t REG_SZ /d 6363 /f' -Verb RunAs"
```

This will execute PowerShell which tries to execute another PowerShell window asking you for credentials and then execute `REG ADD` command and close PowerShell  at the end.

**Keep in mind that you don't have error handling or anything like this so you may want to add them later as they might be very useful**.